# Form post not working on submit. Form object shows null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I post the form by clicking on the save button, it hits the post method but the model parameter is always null.

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionMaster question)
{  
    if (questionLogic.Update(model))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    } 
    return View();
}
```

**View**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>QuestionMaster</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
}
```

Comment: Which object is null? What is `QuestionMaster` class? What is `model` variable in controller? How is `@model` in view defined?

Comment: "question" object is null on form post method

Comment: Is model defined in view: `@model QuestionMaster`?

Comment: show your model please.

Comment: model is QuestionMaster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not posted your model for `QuestionMaster` but from the view code it appears to contain a property named `Question` which is typeof `string`. The problem is that your POST method parameter is also named `question` which causes model binding to fail and the object is null.

Rename the parameter to anything but a name of a property in your model, for example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionMaster model)
```

The reason why your model was `null` on postback is because of how model binding works

1. The `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of
   `QuestionMaster`
2. The posted form's name/value pairs are then checked. If a matching
   property name is found, the value of that property is set.
3. In your case your posting back `Question="The text you entered"` The
   model binder finds the parameter named `question` (i.e. a match) and
   sets it to `"The text you entered"`, but `question` is typeof
   `QuestionMaster` (a complex object, not a `string`) so binding fails
   and the model becomes null.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `HtmlFieldPrefix` in your `EditorFor`.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question, new ViewDataDictionary() { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "QuestionMaster" }})
```

This way the names of the fields will be correct and the model binder will be able to bind them.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've given above, your View is missing a model.

You can add the model to the view as below:

```
@model QuestionMaster
```

This code is typically the first line in your view.

Other than that, can you explain the scope of `model` in your controller action? Where is `model` defined? If it isn't defined, you should understand that using `@Model.someValue` in the view is fine, but accessing `model` in your controller won't work unless your posted model parameter is called `model`.

Assuming that may be another reason for your form being "null", try changing your controller to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionMaster question)
{  
    if (questionLogic.Update(question))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    } 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I suppose he define model, just don't show it here. if not - he is not be able to use strongly typed Helpers.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Will leave it in there in case someone else who hasn't defined the model comes across this answer haha

Answer (score 0):

You can do it what vortex told you or just change your parameter name to anything but "question"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionMaster question2)
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionMaster model)
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(QuestionMaster anything)
```